# Azure Databricks with custom vnet arm template won't connect to the custom vnet

Tags: azure, powershell, databricks, azure-rm-template, azure-databricks

With the following ARM template, I deploy an Azure Databricks with a custom managed Resource Group Name and add the workers to a custom VNET. In the portal this works fine. But When I try to do this inside an ARM template the managed resource groups keep deploying a workers vnet for the workers. I am thinking that I am on the right track but missing one setting. But can't figure it out. Is there anyone who can see what I am missing ?

Source ARM: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-databricks-workspace-with-vnet-injection

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "databricksName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the databricks workspace"
            }
        },
        "pricingTier": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "trial",
                "standard",
                "premium"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The pricing tier of workspace."
            }
        },
        "managedResourceGroupName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the managed resource group that databricks will create"
            }
        },
        "Location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Location of the deployment"
            }
        },
        "vnetName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Name of the virtual network where the Workers would be connected to"
            }
        },
        "privateSubnetName": {
            "defaultValue": "public-subnet",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the private subnet to create."
            }
        },
        "publicSubnetName": {
            "defaultValue": "private-subnet",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the public subnet to create."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "ManagedResourceGroupId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('managedResourceGroupName'))]",
        "vnetId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('databricksName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces",
            "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
            "tags": {
                "description": "MIG6 databricks workspace",
                "costCenter": "WPIPM12SG552"
            },
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "properties": {
                "managedResourceGroupId": "[variables('managedResourceGroupId')]",
                "parameters": {
                    "customVirtualNetworkId": {
                        "value": "[variables('vnetId')]"
                    },
                    "customPublicSubnetName": {
                        "value": "[parameters('publicSubnetName')]"
                    },
                    "customPrivateSubnetName": {
                        "value": "[parameters('privateSubnetName')]"
                    }
                }
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('pricingTier')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest the vnet in the template, this works for me:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vnetRG": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicSubnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicSubnetCIDR": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "privateSubnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "privateSubnetCIDR": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "workspaceName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "tier": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "nsgName": {
            "defaultValue": "databricks-nsg",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "environment": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "nestedTemplate",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('vnetRG')]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('vnetName'), '/', parameters('publicSubnetName'))]",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressPrefix": "[parameters('publicSubnetCIDR')]",
                                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                    "id": "[variables('nsgId')]"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('vnetName'), '/', parameters('privateSubnetName'))]",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetName'), '/subnets/', parameters('publicSubnetName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "addressPrefix": "[parameters('privateSubnetCIDR')]",
                                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                    "id": "[variables('nsgId')]"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "parameters": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "name": "[parameters('workspaceName')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "['Microsoft.Resources/deployments/nestedTemplate']"
            ],
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('tier')]"
            },
            "comments": "Please do not use an existing resource group for ManagedResourceGroupId.",
            "properties": {
                "ManagedResourceGroupId": "[variables('managedResourceGroupId')]",
                "parameters": {
                    "customVirtualNetworkId": {
                        "value": "[variables('vnetId')]"
                    },
                    "customPublicSubnetName": {
                        "value": "[parameters('publicSubnetName')]"
                    },
                    "customPrivateSubnetName": {
                        "value": "[parameters('privateSubnetName')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "managedResourceGroupId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', variables('managedResourceGroupName'))]",
        "managedResourceGroupName": "[concat(resourceGroup().name,'-DATABRICKS-MANAGED')]",
        "vnetId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('vnetRG'), '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetName'))]",
        "nsgId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('vnetRG'), '/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('nsgName'))]"
    },
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: What do you use for your NSG and addressprefix parameters for your subnet. 
Because I can't understand why it would make a difference to place the Vnet creation inside the ARM as it is deployed before databricks.
PS: this is not to bother your answer that could work fine, it's just My customer already has a vnet created and it has to be inside that vnet.

Comment: It's fine to point at the existing vnet - either make sure the settings are identical - or replace with a linked template from the original vnet deployment. So you could just export the vnet template and put that in here - if it has other subnets you can safely remove them. Easy enough to test with a dummy vnet.

Comment: I am testing with a dummy vnet atm :) 
But in any case the databricks is creating a vnet for the workers in the managed resource group and not using the existing vnet.

Comment: It still creates a vnet inside the managed resource group (not sure why). But you should also be connected to your assigned vnet. If you look at your vnet (unmanaged) you should see the vm's connected?

Comment: Did not get to that step. maybe that's the reason why. I thought it won't create a vnet in the managed resource group. testing it out in a bit.

Comment: Well this is awkward. It was already connected I just didn't get to the step to test the clusters inside the workspace. Just did that and It was connected to the existing VNET. Thnx a lot simon.
Does this mean that I can delete the VNET inside the management resource group ?

Comment: It won't let you - there is a lock on it that you can't remove.